# Chrome session remains after deleting cookie and then refreshing

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

Problem: When I delete my session cookie and hit refresh in chrome all my form data and other settings remain. (essentially the session is still active)

- When I close Chrome and relaunch everything is fine. Session is cleared. (I am running the no history extension so perhaps this has some effect on this behavior)

What could be causing this?